# What would be the outcome of the convolution of two images?

Tags: fft, convolution, ifft, deconvolution

1. Lena

   [image]
2. Mask

   [image]

I have written a C# code which produces the following output.

[image]

1. Is my output correct?
2. Am I padding in the correct way?

Comment: Can you please convert your colour picture into a grayscale image? To an extent, the [way you do this conversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale) will affect the answer. In the meantime, you will likely end up with a "cake" with roughly 6 sectors set at different levels. BLUE will generally be the lowest and GREEN the highest. So, your $h(\theta)=a(\theta)+(b(\theta)-a(\theta)) \cdot \delta(n)$ with $a(\theta), b(\theta)$ are the levels as a function of angle ($\theta$). That's [varying degrees of bass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectangular_function) per $\theta$.

Comment: Sorry, instead of $\delta$ that should have been $u$, i.e. the step function.

Comment: "acting as a mask": what do you mean ???

Comment: What's your idea ? This will compute the correlation between the mask and the image, which will be low everywhere as there is no matching between the images. You are essentially performing a low-pass filtering, which will essentially erase the image content, with a slight preference for six main directions.

Comment: @anonymous: they don't tell their purpose either. In their case the images are more comparable. You haven't answered.

Comment: In this new picture, you are not convolving with the mask image but with Lenna itself. Are you really expecting to get the same result as Brian ???

Comment: This becomes ridiculous. Why don't you show the same case as Brian did ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust, 

I want to `Convolve` Lena with a kernel/mask. The kernel/mask I would use would be another image, rather than a matrix of numerical values.

I would zero-pad (2). Convert both of them into a matrix of complex numbers. Apply FFT to both of them to obtain another pair of complex matrices. Then, I would multiply them element by element (if that is the definition of Convolution). Then I would apply I-FFT to the result of multiplication. But, my output seems to be not coming as expected.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, question edited.

Comment: I would suggest that the question is off-topic for this SE because it is about DSP software development using C#. User @Brian has already answered the core of the question and his answer should be accepted. Your "convolved" image could be correct but it suffers from overflow.See how you can solve this in the last diagram of my response (You still need to `round(E*255)` to convert to grayscale **image**). Please consider rapid prototyping in something like Octave or Scilab first before moving on to "production" code with possible optimisations. You can test and verify things much quicker there.

Comment: @anonymous: what you see is a display artifact. The values in your image exceed the expected range, so that there is a wraparound effect, showing isocurves. After you've fixed that, the output will be similar to Brian's. A picture of essentially no interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MATLAB to get the 2D convolution of these images. Before you do so, you'll want to convert image 2 to grayscale and convert both to double.

The result has a very large range, so I normalized the second image.

```
lena = im2double(imread('lena.jpg'));
color = im2double(rgb2gray(imread('color.jpg')));
out = conv2(lena, color./sum(sum(color)));
```

[image]

If you happen to be interested in blending images together, you might want to check out [this paper](http://persci.mit.edu/pub_pdfs/spline83.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Brian's response, this is how your "convolution kernel" looks like in "3D" (i.e, treating the colour image as a [height map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heightmap) ):

[image: Kernel as a heightmap]

To reproduce ([Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/)):

```
U = imread("pie.png"); %Where pie.png is a grayscale image
surf(double(U));
```

The reason for the blue being at the lowest level is because it has [the smallest contribution to the grayscale value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale) and conversely green is highest because it has the highest contribution.

The jagged rim is the thin border marking the circle around the [hue wheel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hue). If we now take the vertical cross section, it looks like this:

[image: Vertical cross section]

Via

```
plot(U(:,128));
```

And the horizontal cross section, looks like this:

[image: Horizontal Cross Section]

Via

```
plot(U(128,:));
```

The spikes certainly make things interesting (because they require a lot of harmonics for their formation) but the frequency domain of such "pulses" will look a little something like this:

[image: Frequency Domain]

Via

```
semilogy(abs(fft(double(U(128,:))./sum(double(U(128,:))))));
```

And its three dimensional version looks like this:

[image: 2d spectrum]

Via

```
surf(fftshift(log10(1+abs(fft2(double(U))))));
```

(Please note, the `log10(1+something)` is [this logarithmic transformation](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/pixlog.htm) which previously was handled by the [semilogy plot](http://octave.sourceforge.net/octave/function/semilogy.html)).

And if you look at it from above (just like we do with images), it looks like this:

[image: 3d plot top view]

Via

```
P = abs(fft2(double(U));
V = fftshift(log10(1+P));
E = V-min(min(V)); %Align the minimum to zero
E = E./max(max(E)); %Divide by maximum to align the maximum value to 1
surf(E); %And once you have the plot, rotate it to the top view, or change its view via one of the relevant functions.
```

Where the "varying degrees of bass" are visible (those red streaks), as we "sweep" around the complex plane at some angle $\theta$.

Hope this helps.